# Firedac slow when connecting to PostgreSQL DB on a VPS

Tags: delphi, firedac

there.

I am facing some strange behavior when connection with Firedac to a PostgreSQL 9.4 database running on a VPS. My delphi is Sidney 10.4.2, but I did test with Seattle too, having the same issue.

I have a test executable which connects to a PostgreSQL 9.4 running on a Ubuntu VPS. My ping to this VPS is around 20ms and it is stable. This VPS is a test server and it is used only by me. There's no one connected to it.

In the test executable, a have 11 different queries, each one selecting row from on table of the same DB. Theses queries return from zero to 2 records (depends of the table) (I mean, we have a very small resultset here).

My question is: if I have a executable connecting to a DB on a VPS, doing "select" on tables, running in the same machine and Internet link, why sometimes it takes a lot to execute, and sometimes it is fast?

Someone could say: "maybe your Internet link is unstable" or "maybe there's some high cpu usage job running in your server". But, if it was true, if I open two instances of the executable, both should be slow, right?

If I open two instances of the same exe, one is fast, other is slow, not exactly in this order.

Trying to eliminate possible causes, I've created the same executable using ZeosLib, to compare them. Zeoslib seems to be to much stable than Firedac in this scenario.

By the way, to better show what I mean, I've recorded a video. The link is:

https://vimeo.com/569074153

In this video, I open two instances of the Firedac exe, and two instances of the Zeoslib exe to compare them. As you may note, Firedac exes show strange behavior, while Zeoslib exes shows an stable behavior.

JUST TO REMEMBER: the DB server, the database and the queries are exact the same in all instances. The properties of all queries controls (TFQQuery or TZQuery) are the same.

Does somebody have any idea of how can I fix this in the Firedac executable?

Thank you in advance,

Leandro

Comment: Is Zeos query unidirectional?

Comment: No... both  (firedac and zeos) are not unidirectional, because if I fix this issue, I'll need to link these queries to grids, so unidirectional would not word for me. thank you.

Comment: Try with larger RowsetSize. For example Query.FetchOptions.RowsetSize = 5000

Comment: @Branko I did the test, but the strange behavior remains. I tested with mode = fmAll too.

Comment: fmAll cannot affect performance, it just means that open fetch all records. Now have I seen that you transfer very few records, so RowsetSize is not important (btw default = 50). At the moment, I have no idea what could be the cause of your problem.